# how to alternate through values of a *multiple parameter than can include any iterator or generator

Tags: python

Assuming that your are restricted from using outside functions such as zip or any itertool how can you alternately iterate though a parameter containing multiple iterator/generators so that the first index of each is printed then second, third respectively etc..

```
def function(*arguments):
    for a in arguments:   
        iterator = iter(a)
        yield next(a)
```

I have been stuck trying to figure out a way of going to the next index of each value on each iterable. As of now i am able to print the first indexes of each but I am confused as to how to implement to the next step after trying Try and except statements with while loops. I am also confused as to how the `StopIteration` exception could work in this case.

so for example using this function in the following way:

```
for i in function('123', '4567', '89XY'):
    print(i,end='')
```

would print:

```
1,4,8,2,5,9,3,6,X,7,Y
```

Comment: `Assuming that your are restricted from using outside functions such as zip or any itertool` - Why?

Comment: Would you not want to use something like `range` either?

Comment: You could at least look at the `roundrobin` [recipe from `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes); it does what you want, and you could try modifying it with the pure python equivalents provided for the relevant `itertools` functions

Comment: *'Implement zip() without using zip()'* But why? Is this just code-golf?

Answer (score 2):

```
def function(*args):
    it = [iter(x) for x in args]
    while True:
        more = False
        for i in it:
            try:
                yield(next(i))
                more = True
            except StopIteration:
                pass
        if not more:
            break
```

Comment: Can you explain why the the StopIteration exception needs to be caught and passed here?

Comment: @user2918863 because some of your iterables might run out before the others do (e.g. `'123'` in your example).

Comment: also is there a specific name for creating control structures such as the one created with more= False to break out of the loop at some point in the last 2 blocks of code? I really struggle with this aspect of programming and would like to look into it more

Answer (score 0):

The [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) documentation has pure python equivalents for its methods. In this case, `izip` is what you seek:

```
def izip(*iterables):
    # izip('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax By
    iterators = map(iter, iterables)
    while iterators:
        yield tuple(map(next, iterators))
```

and used (strings being iterable):

```
for i in izip('abc', '123', 'pqr'):
    print i
```

yields

```
('a', '1', 'p')
('b', '2', 'q')
('c', '3', 'r')
```

Comment: `izip_longest`, given that the OP's inputs vary in length

Answer (score 0):

May be that:

```python
def function(*args):
    iters = map(iter, args)
    while iters:
        for iter_arg in iters:
            try:
                yield iter_arg.next()
            except StopIteration:
                iters.remove(iter_arg)
```

Comment: You can't safely remove from the list while iterating over it